# If trigonometric series is $0$ everywhere, then its coefficients are $0$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

> How to prove that if $\forall x \in \mathbb R, \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{inx} = 0$, then $c_n=0$ for all $n$ ?

I feel something could be done by integrating the series, but how to switch the sum and the integral then ? Nothing is assumed on the type of convergence or the regularity of $c_n$ (is it in $\ell^2$).

Comment: The way the question is written strongly hints toward (at least) pointwise convergence. But even convergence at a single $x\in \mathbb{R}$ would imply that the coefficients tend to $0$, and for coefficients of at most polynomial growth, the vanishing of the coefficients already follows from convergence in the sense of distributions.

Comment: A nice proof, and much more, can be found in [these notes](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~kechris/papers/uniqueness.pdf) by Alexander Kechris. This is an interesting topic; in a sense, pursuing it led to the creation of set theory.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you. It looks like Cantor's proof is based on a sequence of elaborate lemmas. Do you know a simpler or shorter proof ?

Comment: They are actually fairly straightforward. I doubt anything simpler is possible.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Since the summation is over $\mathbb{Z}$ ( so grouping $n$ and $-n$ is perhaps meant implicitly) the convergence to $0$ of $c_n$ as $|n|\to \infty$ still requires an argument.

Comment: Thanks @AndrésE.Caicedo for those notes. I was myself looking for Cantor's proof for quite some time. +1 to OP for thus nice question.