# If a trigonometric series equals zero at every point, will its coefficients all be zero?

Tags: fourier-analysis, functional-equations, trigonometric-series

I was studying Fourier analysis recently and I came to the following question:

> Given a trigonometric series (Here I express it in the form of Fourier
> series, but it's not necessarily the Fourier series of some functions,
> don't be mesled!) $$\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos
> > nx+b_n\sin nx),x\in \mathbb{R}$$ where
> $a_0,a_n,b_n\in\mathbb{R},\forall n\geq 1.$ If such a series converges
> to $0$ for  any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (just pointwise convergence), namely
> $$\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx)=0,\forall
>  x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}$$ can we derive that $a_0=0$ and $a_n=b_n=0,\forall
>  n\geq 1$ ?

I find it hard to handle this question because the convergence in $(1)$ is only pointwise, so neither the tool of integral nor differential can be applied. Moreover, the theorems I have studied in Fourier analysis only deal with the properties of the coefficients of Fourier series, so I cannot apply them, too. I also take some values of $x$ in $(1)$ ($x=k\pi,2k\pi,k\pi+\frac{1}{2}\pi, e.t.c$) but I only get some equations of power series and cannot solve it. Is there anyone who can help me or give me some hints?

Comment: Some possibly helpful  comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2399143/42969

Comment: Oh yes, it's of great help! And it seems that my question is repeated, but I did not find it before I asked this question...@MartinR

Comment: A proper *answer* (either here or to the older question) would still be good. Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted at any time.

Comment: @MartinR I found a post on this topic with an answer. Though it's still not the best considering it's just one sentence and then a link, hence not really a proper answer, but at least it's in an answer I guess... https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2893328/1104384